# How to copy content in Network tab of Dart DevTools in VS Code?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have a struggle with copying content of an API in `Dart DevTools` -> `Network` -> `Overview` -> `Request uri`. How to copy that text properly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The description is pretty straigh forward. When I try to copy/paste any information from the DevTools-Network it is fail

Comment: @Heikkisorsa Unfortunately no

Comment: There is a GitHub issue about that. You can follow at https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/5276

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't. There might be an issue related to webview inside VSCode. I'm not sure about that.

#### Workaround

Open DevTool in browser, then click on Network tab at the top bar. You can copy whatever you want inside the browser instead of using VSCode.